# Adding day and month fields to date field which doesn't contain them

Tags: python, datetime

Say we have a list like this:

```
['1987', '1994-04', '2001-05-03']
```

We would like to convert these strings into `datetime` objects with a consistent format, then back into strings, something like this:

```
['1987-01-01', '1994-04-01', '2001-05-03']
```

In this case, we have decided if the date doesn't contain a month or a day, we set it to the first of that respective field. Is there a way to achieve this using a datetime or only by string detection?

Comment: A large part of computer programming is problem solving. By this I mean, we come up with solutions and then test them out to see if we get the results we want. If I were to ttry to solve this, I would start by reading the `datetime` documentation to see if there's any way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read about [datetime module](https://pymotw.com/3/datetime/index.html) to understand the basics of handling dates and date-like strings in Python.

The below approach using [`try-except`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html) is one of the many ways to achieve the desired outcome.:

```
from datetime import datetime


strings = ['1987', '1994-04', '2001-05-03']

INPUT_FORMATS = ('%Y', '%Y-%m', '%Y-%m-%d')
OUTPUT_FORMAT = '%Y-%m-%d'

output = []
for s in strings:
    dt = None
    for f in INPUT_FORMATS:
        try:
            dt = datetime.strptime(s, f)
            break
        except ValueError:
            pass
        except:
            raise
     
    if not dt:
         raise ValueError("%s doesn't match any of the formats" % s)

    output.append(dt.date().strftime(OUTPUT_FORMAT))

print(output)
```

Output:

```
['1987-01-01', '1994-04-01', '2001-05-03']
```

*The above code will work only with date formats listed in `formats` variable. You can add additional formats to it if you know them beforehand.*